# Return list from static async Task method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a Task method that calls a remote API that takes the returned JSON and converts the data to C# objects, and displays the data on a console. I would like this method to return the list as well so I can consume it elsewhere can someone show me how as I keep on getting error when I change the method signature to a list type, all replies appreciated! -

```
// asynchronous retrieve data from api
public static async Task GetUser()
{
     //baseUrl
     string baseUrl = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
     try
     {
          // HttpClient implements a IDisposable interface
          using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

          //initiate Get Request 
          using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))

          //convert response to c# object
          using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
          {
              //convert data content to string using await
              var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              //If the data is not null, parse(deserialize) the data to a C# object
              if (data != null)
              {
                   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserList>(data);
                   foreach (var u in result.Results)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Url: {1}", u.Name, u.Url);
                   }
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("No returned data");
              }
          }
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(exception);
     }
}
```

User.cs -

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

    }
```

UserList.cs -

```
  public class UserList
    {
        public List<User> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Update your method function <Task<UserList>> and then update the function with return. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: How is `UserList` declared?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what the error message is you see. Most likely you get an error because you don't return a value in all cases. Either don't catch all exceptions or make sure you return a value even if an exception happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static async Task<UserList>  GetUser()
        {
            //baseUrl
            string baseUrl = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
            try
            {
                // HttpClient implements a IDisposable interface
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //initiate Get Request 
                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))
                    {
                        //convert response to c# object
                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                        {
                            //convert data content to string using await
                            var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            //If the data is not null, parse(deserialize) the data to a C# object
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserList>(data);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

You can use await after, like this:

```
UserList test =  await GetUser();
```

Comment: This works using public static async Task<UserList> GetUsers() signature and not as suggested by Vinícius i.e Task<List<UseList>> The error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'PBXApp.UserList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PBXApp.UserList>

Comment: Appreciate all the responses!

Answer (score 1):

```
// asynchronous retrieve data from api
public static async Task<List<User>> GetUser()
{
    //Connect to the webservice and get the data     
    //Parse the data into a list of Users
    var myList = parseResultJsonFromServer(serverResult);

    //myList is of type List<User> and ready to be returned
    return myList
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
the return has to be a Task<List<User>>, not just List<User>
```